# Node.js socket.io get cookie (on server - Debian)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, debian

My script runs well on my computer, but fails on my server (Debian), with Socket.io. When I do:

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshake, callback) {
  console.log(handshake.headers);
  callback(null, true);
});
```

I do get the `handshake.headers.cookies` (io and session cookies) when running on localhost. But when I run the scripts on my server (some version of node and everything), I only get the "io" cookie, that is not even yet in the browser. Do you have any idea why?

EDIT: the cookies are set in the browser in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just the way I initialised socket.io, I realised that it worked when going on the IP of the server and not on the domain name.
So now I simply do that:

```
socket = io(window.location.hostname);
```